# Oracle 10g Partitioning: Can I partition a subtable?

Tags: oracle, partitioning

I have a main table with a primary key and a partition column (a date) and five subtables which use foreign key references to the primary key.

Is there a way with Oracle 10g to partition the subtables in the same way as the main table *without* duplicating the partition column?

Comment: Upgrade if you can.... as what Todd said is correct but don't worry about the extra column if you can't. Typically it's a column that isn't changing, so you shouldn't have update concerns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you need 11g for that function.